# Escaping the "<" less than sign and ">" greater than sign in Netsuite Javascript / Restlet

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I have address data in Netsuite that looks like the following, note that in contains a "<" and ">" then sign along with other characters that need to be escaped to be valid characters in an XML document.
12 ENTERPRISE RD UNIT 3 & 4 < 5 > "6" '7'

In javascript (netsuites version of javascript) I have tried the following "FOR" loop, the data ends up with the < and > converted into   & lt ; and & gt ;  (as seen below without the spaces)
12 ENTERPRISE RD UNIT 3 & 4 & lt ; 5 & gt ; "6" '7'

```
var EscapedField = '';
for (var pos = 0; pos < FieldToEscape.length; pos++) 
    {             
        switch (FieldToEscape.charAt(pos)) 
        {
        // escape "less than"   
        case "<":
            EscapedField = EscapedField + '&lt;'
            break;
        // escape "greater than" 
        case ">":
            EscapedField = EscapedField + '&gt;' 
            break;
        default:
            EscapedField = EscapedField + FieldToEscape.charAt(pos)
            break;
       }
    }
```

---

Per a suggestion by egrubaugh360 I tried the following in "Netsuite" / Javascript ,

1)  I have a result set that contains a address that contains ( & , < , > , " , ') , (i.e ampersand, Less Than, Greater Than, Double Quote, Single Quote )

2)  when you look at the values in the debugger they are valid

3)  After executing the NS function nlapiEscapeXML on the dataset the "<"  and ">" are converted to  & lt ;  and  & gt ;  the actual escaped characters

var ADDRLINE1 = nlapiEscapeXML(results[i].getValue('shipaddress1'));

$ results[i].getValue('shipaddress1')

> 12 ENTERPRISE RD UNIT 3 & 4 < 5 > "6" '7'

$ ADDRLINE1

> 12 ENTERPRISE RD UNIT 3 & 4 & lt; 5 & gt; "6" '7'

4) In NetSuite / javascript I have tried many permutations of escaping “<” and “>” but they all end up being converted to <  and  >

I am going to try a string substitution for <  and  &gt within the ETL tool (Jitterbit) that is processing the file, that should work, but its hooky.

5) thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

The NetSuite API contains a method for this purpose: `nlapiEscapeXML` I recommend investigating this method in NetSuite Help. It accepts a single String parameter and (should) return that same string with any XML control characters escaped appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2.1 or 2.0 there is a function in 'N/xml' module 'xml.escape' use this method to escape that.

If this also does not work then use JavaScript replace method with regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try using triple handlebars when calling the original field to your code (in search or formulas)

e.g. "{{{field_name}}}"

Worked for me with a similar issue, totally frustrated until I found this. hope it helps.